# NSDate gets wrong date from NSString

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

What I'm trying to do is have an NSDate with the correct current time. When I convert the date into a string the time is correct, but when I'm converting back to an NSDate, the time is just off.

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate* myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"datete:%@ and %@", myDate, dateString);
```

2014-02-22 00:18:00 +0000 and 21-02-2014 16:18

Comment: It would really help if you showed the output from the `NSLog`. And it's probably not wrong. It's just how `NSDate` gets logged - in the UTC timezone.

Comment: BTW - there is no need to set the date formatter's locale to the current locale - that is the default.

Comment: I updated the original post with the nslog.

Comment: @Bomiz see my answer for explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When printing `NSDate` objects, remember that `description` returns the date in UTC. So if you see a difference between the two objects, make sure you take into account your timezone and add that to the printed value of the `NSDate`.

When you want to correctly print them in your logs and/or UI, you should use a date formatter, rather than printing the NSDate object directly. Date formatters take the local timezone and system locale, and print the dates correctly.

Comment: How would I go about adding the correct amount? It's different for different timezones

Comment: @Bomiz I meant add in your head so you can check for correctness. `NSDate` objects do not hold any timezone information. When you want to correctly print them in your logs and/or UI, you should use a date formatter, rather than printing the `NSDate` object directly.

Comment: What I am doing is Saving the current date as a userdefault. I cannot save the formatter. So what I thought was to convert it back into an NSDate for it to save. But would it be possible to convert the NSString with the correct date to an NSDate containing the same date as the string?

Comment: @Bomiz Uhm, why are you converting an `NSDate` object into anything? It can be saved in user defaults as is. See documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-CIHDHAGB

Comment: Sorry, disband this question. What was messing with me was some completely different block of code that I fixed. Thank you though!!!